# What is wrong with my AppleScript code? Pulling URL from search

Tags: html, excel, macos, applescript

I have a list of lots of UPCs where I need to search for the UPC on Amazon, and then return the URL of the first product that pops up. I am trying to write an AppleScript to do this quickly, where I can just change the number of iterations based on how many UPCs I have to search.

All the search links for the UPCs are in an Excel file in column A (e.g. https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dtoys-and-games&field-keywords=889698110563). Column B is blank to put the intended link for the result.

Below is what I have written, and it's not working. Please help me troubleshoot!

```
repeat 5 times
    activate application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Microsoft Excel"
        keystroke "c" using command down
        key code 124
    end tell

    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome"
        keystroke "l" using command down
        keystroke "v" using command down
        key code 36
    end tell

    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome"
        set frontmost to true
        repeat 39 times
            keystroke tab
        end repeat
        key code 36
    end tell

    tell application "Google Chrome"
        set the clipboard to (URL of active tab of first window as text)
    end tell

    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Microsoft Excel"
        keystroke "v" using command down
        key code 125
        key code 123
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you want help debugging code, it really should to conform to [How to create a Minimal, Complete,and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Just saying "Below is what I have written, and it's not working. Please help me troubleshoot!" doesn't cut it! That said, I'd take an entirely different approach then trying to use UI Scripting. By that I mean, doing away with code like `repeat 39 times keystroke tab`. Frankly, the only time something like that should be used is when there is absolutely no other way to accomplish that task.

Comment: why do you use system events to control excel if you can directly access excel? or chrome... try accessing apps directly with applescript

Answer (score 1):

I do not have or use **Excel**, so I would be no help with coding for its direct usage, however here is an *example* **AppleScrip**t *script* of how I might *code* it to achieve the goal of having the **UPC Search URL** and the corresponding **URL** of the *first item returned* for each of the **UPC Search URLs**, in a file that can then be *imported/opened* in e.g. **Excel**, or similar app.

Starting with a *plain text* file that contains just the **UPC Search URLs**, i.e. the contents of **Column A**, e.g.:

```
https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dtoys-and-games&field-keywords=889698110563
https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dtoys-and-games&field-keywords=889698110532
https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dtoys-and-games&field-keywords=745559220041
https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dtoys-and-games&field-keywords=849803049096
https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dtoys-and-games&field-keywords=745559239104
```

In **Script Editor**... I'd read this file into a *variable*, creating an **AppleScript** *list* from it, having each search **URL** open one at a time in **Google Chrome**. Then using **JavaScript**, vs. tabbing 39 times, to retrieve the **URL** of the *first item returned* of each **UPC Search URL**, which in turn is placed into another **AppleScript** *list*. I would then *concatenate* the two **AppleScript** *lists* into a *tab delimitated* file that can then be imported/opened in whatever app is registered to handle files having a **.csv** *extension*.

From there, you can save it as a **.xls/.xlsx** file or copy and paste the info to the original **Excel** file or whatever.

- Note: To properly open a **.csv** file in **Excel**, it must be imported (in MSO 2016, File > Import). Just double-clicking it, while it will open, it will not parse the *tab* delimiter.

**Example AppleScript *code*:**

```
--  # Input File

set UPC_File to POSIX path of (path to documents folder as text) & "UPC Search List.txt"

--  # Output File

set UPC_URL_File to POSIX path of (path to documents folder as text) & "UPC URL List.csv"

--  # Use a couple AppleScript Lists to hold information for processing.

set UPC_Search_List to {}
set URL_Returned_List to {}

--  # Read contents of UPC_File into a variable.

set UPC_File_Content to do shell script "cat " & quoted form of UPC_File

--  # Load UPC_Search_List from UPC_File_Content variable.

repeat with UPC_Search_URL in paragraphs of text of UPC_File_Content
    set end of UPC_Search_List to UPC_Search_URL as text
end repeat

--  # Open a new Google Chrome window to 'about:blank'.
--  # This is used as a buffer to keep the window from 
--  # being closed as the ensuing active tab is closed.

tell application "Google Chrome"
    make new window
    activate
    set URL of active tab of front window to "about:blank"
    delay 1
    --  # Load corresponding URL_Returned_List for each item in UPC_Search_List.
    repeat with thisURL in UPC_Search_List
        open location thisURL
        --  # Wait for Tab to finish loading.
        repeat until (loading of active tab of window 1 is false)
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        --  # Get URL of first item returned of UPC Search.
        try
            tell active tab of front window
                set end of URL_Returned_List to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal')[0].href;"
            end tell
        on error
            set end of URL_Returned_List to missing value
        end try
        delay 3 -- # A delay is necessary so as not to hammer the website with requests, which can/may lead to blacklisting your IP Address.
        close active tab of front window
    end repeat
    close front window
end tell

--  # Concatenate UPC_Search_List and URL_Returned_List into UPC_URL_File creating a tab delimited file.

repeat with i from 1 to count of UPC_Search_List
    do shell script "echo " & quoted form of item i of UPC_Search_List & quoted form of tab & quoted form of item i of URL_Returned_List & " >> " & quoted form of UPC_URL_File
end repeat

--  # Inform user script finished.

activate
display dialog "Processing of the UPC Search List has finished." buttons {"OK"} default button 1
```

You can now **Import** the **Output File** into **Excel**.

---

Here's a version of the *example* **AppleScript** *script* that uses **Excel** directly:

- It still uses two **AppleScript** *lists*, first loading the *value* of the *cells* in **Column A** for the number of *rows* specified to one of the *lists*, Then gets the corresponding **URL** of the *first item returned* in **Google Chrome**, loading it into the second *list*. Then the *value* of the *cells* in **Column B** get set from the second *list*.

**Example AppleScript *code*:**

```
--  # Use a couple AppleScript Lists to hold information for processing.

set UPC_Search_List to {}
set URL_Returned_List to {}

--  # Load UPC_Search_List from Excel.

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell sheet 1 of window 1
        repeat with i from 1 to 5
            set end of UPC_Search_List to value of cell ("A" & i)
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell

--  # Open a new Google Chrome window to 'about:blank'.
--  # This is used as a buffer to keep the window from 
--  # being closed as the ensuing active tab is closed.

tell application "Google Chrome"
    make new window
    activate
    set URL of active tab of front window to "about:blank"
    delay 1
    --  # Load corresponding URL_Returned_List for each item in UPC_Search_List.
    repeat with thisURL in UPC_Search_List
        open location thisURL
        --  # Wait for Tab to finish loading.
        repeat until (loading of active tab of window 1 is false)
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        --  # Get URL of first item returned of UPC Search.
        try
            tell active tab of front window
                set end of URL_Returned_List to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal')[0].href;"
            end tell
        on error
            set end of URL_Returned_List to missing value
        end try
        delay 3 -- # A delay is necessary so as not to hammer the website with requests, which can/may lead to blacklisting your IP Address.
        close active tab of front window
    end repeat
    close front window
end tell

--  # Write URL_Returned_List to Excel.

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell sheet 1 of window 1
        repeat with i from 1 to 5
            set value of cell ("B" & i) to item i of URL_Returned_List
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell

--  # Inform user script finished.

activate
display dialog "Processing of the UPC Search List has finished." buttons {"OK"} default button 1
```

**NOTE:** These are just *example* **AppleScript** *scripts* and can be coded differently. Aside from one `try` and `on error` *statement*, they do not contain any other *error handling* that may be deemed appropriate, necessary and or wanted. The onus is upon the User to implement *error handing* accordingly.